# embeding an icon for a table column

Tags: php, html

i have a table and i want to put a .png image on the edit column but the image is no visible instead on seeing the word edit i want to see an icon image for edit
this is my code

```
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a><img src="images/glyphicons_016_bin.png" /></font></b></td>';
```

is there any way i can make it visible?? or is there a way i can do? a better way of doing it,i will greatly appreciate thanks alot in advance

Comment: You want the image and the "Edit" text both?

Comment: no just the image.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS `background-image` property

```
a.class_name {
   background-image: url(../whatever.png);
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   background-position: /* If Required */;
}
```

You can also simply try this, just make sure the image path is correct

```
<a href="#"><img src="" /></a>
```

> Note: `<font>` tag is deprecated

Comment: well i have two columns i want one to have the delete image but when i use your method the image is apperaing even in the second colomn